# Why ajax call's timeout not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, timeout

In my ASPX page I call a javascript function which contains an Ajax call with 5 seconds timeout.

I first try to call this function with internet connection off and timeout works properly. But when I call this function for the second time, Ajax call directly calls success function, without waiting for timeout and subsequent error function.

Here is the the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: pageUrl + "/SubmitAnsGetNewQue",
     data: jsonParamsForSbmt,
     timeout: 5000,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     async: true,
     success: SetNextQueSet,
     error: OnErrorCall
});
```

Comment: Is your connection still OFF on your second call? Because if it's ON, you likely got a quick response which explains the *success* and quick response.

Comment: Yes my connection is till OFF...

Answer (score 3):

`timeout` isn't what you think in this context, it's the amount of time in miliseconds that jQuery will wait for the ajax request to return.

If it took more than 5 seconds to the server to reply, the callbacks won't fire.

**timeout**

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Yes... So? Isn't OP expecting for the same?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, I believe he think there should be a pause of 5 seconds between request. Actually I'm not so sure what he meant nor what he did.

Comment: It might be that OP wanted to pause requests when there's no connection. It is of course much more interesting that second call executes `success` handler... It should still wait for the timeout and execute the `error` handler.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, I think he turned the connection on: _"I **first try to call this function with internet connection off** and timeout works properly. But when I call this function for the second time,"_

Comment: internet connection is still off when i call sencond time

Comment: Thanks to all for reply, 
I don't want to pause the requests, at second time, it should call error function when it is not get response...that what I want....